# Columnstore Indexing technology in MySQL with vector based batch processing

Tags: mysql, database, sql-server-2008, phpmyadmin, mining

I am using MySQL as a database and as the database is large, it has been indexed columnwise. But now there is the requirement to use the MSSQL like method for indexing as it has been said to perform faster whose link is as below:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/dataplatforminsider/archive/2011/08/04/columnstore-indexes-a-new-feature-in-sql-server-known-as-project-apollo.aspx

According to it, it uses columnstore indexes along with Vector-based batch processing. 
So i wanna know that, is there any similar technique in MySQL for the fast processing to fetch the data from DB??????

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For more information, currently the database is working fine the there is the requirement of more fast processing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [InfoBright](http://www.infobright.org/) mysql storage engine. It is pretty good one.